# synchronised block for class not working

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following piece of code in a Multithreaded environment:

```
   static int c=0;
    ..
    ..
    Scanner fileContent = new Scanner(this.content);    
    while (fileContent.hasNextLine()) {
        fileContent.nextLine();
        synchronized (SameClassWhereCodeResides.class) {
            c=c+1;
            if(c%100==0)
                System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
```

I am getting results which are not multiple of 100. As per my understanding the `synchronised` block on a class itself ensures one thread to execute the block for all instances. What am I doing wrong?

Update:
Here is the complete code

```
public class CallRestServiceWorker extends S3Client implements Runnable {

    public CallRestServiceWorker(S3ObjectSummary s3ObjectSummary) {
        this.s3ObjectSummary = s3ObjectSummary;
    }
       static int c=0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        AmazonS3 s3cli = this.getS3Client();
        S3Object s3FileObject = s3cli
                .getObject(new GetObjectRequest(this.s3ObjectSummary.getBucketName(), this.s3ObjectSummary.getKey()));
        Scanner fileContent = new Scanner(s3FileObject.getObjectContent());
        int counter = 0;
        while (fileContent.hasNextLine()) {
            fileContent.nextLine();
            synchronized (CallRestServiceWorker.class) {
            c=c+1;
            if(c%100==0)
            System.out.println(c);
            }

        }

    }
```

In the main thread I have an executor service

```
executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);        
    for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : result.getObjectSummaries()) {
                    this.futures.add(executor.submit(new CallRestServiceWorker(objectSummary)));
                }
```

Comment: Please write your code as a [mcve].

Comment: I cant use this keyword because every thread have their own instance of this class

Comment: are you sure `c = c + 1` is the only place `c` is changed?

Comment: 100% sure......

Comment: Why is `c` shared anyway?

Comment: There are many threads having instance of this class

Comment: The same instance? Or one instance each? I can't imagine a good reason why you would have a static counter like that.

Comment: one instance each, I have edited the code for more understanding

Comment: Post code that reproduces the problem. The code you posted doesn’t even run. See [mcve]

Comment: @masSdev, can you post a code snippet which we can run and examine the results?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko  Code updated

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt code updated

Comment: @masSdev, are you printing `c` somewhere outside of `run`? *"I am getting results which are not multiple of 100"* - where are you getting them?

Comment: Is that really the code? I see an unused `int counter` there. If that is all the code there is, it's *impossible* for you to print anything but multiples of `100` for `c`.

Comment: @Kayaman I have deleted all other codes ,to test only this scenario . I am using the same code ,that i have posted here

Comment: So what kind of values are you getting? You might be dealing with a cursed JVM.

Comment: @masSdev, can you post the results you got?

Comment: @Kayaman cursed JVM ?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko if i use for c%100 the frequency of getting error is less.I can reproduce this error if c%100000 is used. following the result:`100000
200000
300000
400000
500000
600000
700000
769872
800000
900000
1000000`

Comment: It's more common than you think. Any time when there's a problem, but it's **impossible** for the code to behave in that way, the chance of a cursed JVM needs to be considered. For example the code you've shown **cannot** behave in a way you describe, so clearly you have a cursed JVM.

Comment: (More likely you're not showing the actual code and there's a typo somewhere or you're running a different version of the code than you're showing, or any other mistake on your part)

Comment: @masSdev, could `769872` be a final value for the `Runnable` which finished its work? it looks like you put `sout` statements somewhere for debug and we see intermediate or final results.

Comment: The cursed JVM strikes again.

Comment: @masSdev, you are welcome! [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @masSdev, you unaccepted my answer, why did you change your mind? is there anything else I can help you with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are printing `c` somewhere outside of the provided snippet (for debugging or other purposes). As a result, we see intermediate or final values of `c` which don't satisfy the condition `c % 100 == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

> As per my understanding synchronised block on class itself ensure one thread to execute the block for all instances.

Yes but only if *every access of `c` synchronises on the same object*.

> What am I doing wrong??

Some other thread is probably changing `c` without synchronising or is synchronising on something else.

Comment: Every thread have it's own instance for this class. So how to stop other threads from changing the value

Comment: @masSdev Synchronization

Comment: I have used the same:)

Comment: technically, it's correct. But it's too broad and doesn't help resolve the issue